# CSS: 100% width minus element on same line

Tags: html, css

How would I make an input element 100% width that is available? So, 100% width minus the width of any other elements on the same line (not knowing the width of those elements)?

```css
.bg {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
 }
input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.4em;
  height: 25px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.button {
  height: 25px;
  padding: 0.4em;
  background: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  text-decoration: none;
 }
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  
  <input type="text" placeholder="100% width - button" /><a class="button" href="#">Click</a>
  
 </div>

<div class="bg">
  
  <input type="text" placeholder="100% width" />
  
 </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2 ways do that:

- use `flexbox`, applying `display:flex` in `.bg` (`.bg2` for demo)  and `flex:1` (or just `flex-grow:1`) in `input`

```css
.bg {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}
.bg2 {
  display: flex;
  border: solid red
}
.bg2 input {
  flex: 1;
}
input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.4em;
  height: 25px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.button {
  height: 25px;
  padding: 0.4em;
  background: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg bg2">

  <input type="text" placeholder="100% width - button" /><a class="button" href="#">Click</a>

</div>

<div class="bg">

  <input type="text" placeholder="100% width" />

</div>
```

- For older versions of IE, use CSS tables

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}
.bg {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
input {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.4em;
  height: 25px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.button {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 25px;
  padding: 0.4em;
  background: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg bg2">

  <input type="text" placeholder="100% width - button" /><a class="button" href="#">Click</a>

</div>

<div class="bg">

  <input type="text" placeholder="100% width" />

</div>
```

Comment: Nice answer, but please do note that flexbox is not supported by IE 9 and below.

Comment: OP said that the width of the second element isn't known, so calc won't be a solution here

Answer (score 2):

Adding `display:flex` to the `.bg`-class works. Flexbox tries to evenly distribute it's child-elements, but since one of the elements has 100% width and there's still another child, the width is adjusted, so everything fits in one row. There is a great guideline for the flex-attribute [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Comment: Thanks for the help.